# How do I make sure swipe function in HTML5 canvas continues to rotate as it is swiped?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, html5-canvas

I have a HTML5 canvas where when swiped right with JQuery swipe events it rotates the image only once 30 degrees and then it stops. 
What I would like to do is to make sure it can be swiped more before it stops and returns and output. 
So, when im on 30 degrees if I don't want that I'd like to be able to swipe more.
I hope I am clear.

I was wondering if someone could have a look at my code and show me a way of doing this please. Thank you..

This is to enable `swiperight` event:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", function() {
  $(".the_canvas").on("swiperight", function() {
    $(".the_canvas").addClass(startRightSpin());
  });
});
```

This is the `swipeRightSpin` function:

```
function startRightSpin() {
  var stopAngle = undefined;
      spinMode == "random";
      stopAngle = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360);

  if ((typeof(stopAngle) !== 'undefined') && (wheelState == 'reset')) {
    stopAngle = (30);
    targetAngle = (30);

    // Now kick off the spinning of the wheel by calling the doSpin function.
    wheelState = 'spinning';
    doSpin();
  }
}
```

and `doSpin()` function calls the prizes function:

```
function prizes() {
  if ((doPrizeDetection) && (prizes)) {
    var times360 = Math.floor(currentAngle / 360);
    var rawAngle = (currentAngle - (360 * times360));
    var relativeAngle = Math.floor(pointerAngle - rawAngle);
    if (relativeAngle < 0)
      relativeAngle = 360 - Math.abs(relativeAngle);
    for (x = 0; x < (prizes.length); x++) {
      if ((relativeAngle >= prizes[x]['startAngle']) && (relativeAngle <= prizes[x]['endAngle'])) {
        alert("You have been selected " + prizes[x]['name'] + "!\nClick 'Okay' if you want another persona.");
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

Please view the code on codePen, I would appreciate any help please.
http://codepen.io/hTeeML/pen/oXMXdz?editors=101

Comment: In `startRightSpin` you say `spinMode == "random";`. The double equals will eval as a boolean and not assign anything. Did you mean `spinMode = "random";`. Also, you use a semicolon at the end of those first two lines, meaning that the 2nd and 3rd will evaluate in the global scope. Did you mean for them to be in the function scope? If so, replace the semicolons at the end of `stopAngle =` and `spinMode =` with commas.

Comment: Also, you're saying `addClass(startRightSpin())`, but `startRightSpin` doesn't even have a return.

Comment: Thank you for your reply firstly.
startRightSpin() calls doSpin() which then calls prize() function.
What I wanted is when I swipe right it only goes on to the next segment in the wheel and the code doesn't do anything else. But instead, I would like to be able to swipe again right until I reach to the segment that I want to. 
But I just don't know how to do it and I'm a beginner and I really need to do this.